# From .csv, read only or split into sections separated by "<string>"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv file that is split in sections, each starting with < string > on a row of its own as in this example. This is followed by a set of columns and their respective rows of values. Columns are not consistent between sections.

```
< section1 ><br>
col1 col2 col3<br>
val1 val2 val3

< section2 ><br>
col3 col4 col5<br>
val4 val5 val6<br>
val7 val8 val9
```

...etc. Is there a way in which I can, either when the file's in .txt or .csv, import each section either:
1) into seperate dataframes? 
2) into the same dataframe, but something like df[section][col]?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the size of your csv, you could read in the entire file into Pandas and split the dataframe into multiple dataframes via a list comprehension.

```
data = '''ï»¿<Network>;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
            Property;Value;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
            Title;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
            Version;6.4;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
            <Sites>;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
            Name;LocationCode;Longitude;Latitude;;;;;;;;;;...'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=None)
```

create a list of dataframe names (the headers of each df)

```
df_names = df[0].str.extract(r'(<[a-zA-Z]+>)')[0].str.strip('<>').dropna().tolist()
```

find the indices for the headers
    regions = df.loc[df[0].str.contains(r'<[a-zA-Z]+')].index.tolist()

```
last_row = df.index[-1]

regions.append(last_row)

from more_itertools import windowed
```

create windows for each  'sub' dataframe

```
regions_window = list(windowed(regions,2))
```

the function helps with some cleanup during the dataframe extraction

```
def some_cleanup(df):
    df.columns = df.iloc[0].str.extract(r'(<[a-zA-z]+>)')[0].str.strip('<>')
    df = df.iloc[1:]
    return df
```

extract the dataframes

```
M = [df.loc[start:end].pipe(some_cleanup) for start,end in regions_window]
```

create a dict with the keys as the dataframe names

```
dataframe_dict = dict(zip(df_names,M))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209078/discussion-on-answer-by-sammywemmy-from-csv-read-only-or-split-into-sections-s).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can take simple approach and read txt file like:

```
with open("dummy.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Now just get the location of each section:

```
sections = [lines.index(line) for line in lines if "<" in line]
```

Then you can use sections to read in between data in pandas dataframe like:

```
for i in range(len(sections)):
    header = lines[sections[i]]
    df = pd.DataFrame(lines[sections[i]+1:sections[i+1]],
                      columns=header)
    print(df.head())
```

Comment: I am getting this error: TypeError: "Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, '<Network>\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n' was passed" 

Here "Network" is the section I'd like the naming to be, either as a seperate df named Network or as df['Network]['subcolumns']

@sau

Comment: If I look at header, it seems to in the right way catch the rows in which the sections start. I tried passing columns=list(header) and columns = [header] without success

Answer (score 1):

There are some great answers here already but I'd recommend a Unix tool! It is shorter and will scale to very large files that don't fit into Pandas.

Assuming your file is called `foo.csv`:

```
awk '/< section/{x=i++"foo_mini";next}{print > x;}' foo.csv
```

Creates as many (numbered) `{n}foo_mini.csv` files as you have sections. (It seeks the pattern `< section`, and then starts a new file from the following line.)

Then for completeness' sake, add the csv extension:

```
for file in *foo_mini; do mv "$file" "${file/foo_mini/foo_mini.csv}"; done
```

You thus have:

```
0foo_mini.csv
1foo_mini.csv
etc...
```

It's then a cinch to read them in with Pandas as separate dataframes, and concat them if you like.

Comment: So true. plus one for the Awk option.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd
new_section = False
header_read = False
data_for_frame = list()
for row in data.splitlines():
    if row.startswith('< '):
        new_section = True
        continue
    if re.match('^\s*$', row):
        new_section = False
        header_read = False
        df = pd.DataFrame(data_for_frame, columns=columns)
        continue
    if new_section:
        if not header_read:
            columns = row.split(' ')
            header_read = True
            continue
        if header_read:
            data_for_frame.append(row.split(' '))
            continue
```

Import might be only, that the CSV file ends with an empty line as well. And you have to take care about the dataframe naming.

The `data.splitlines()` just came from my own short test, you have to replace it with `with open('myfile','r) as f:`and so on.

Comment: Looks like this comes a long way, but I guess when reading it in like a .txt I still need to pick up all the '\t's as seperators?

0    Title\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t            None   
1  Version\t6.4\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t...            None   
2  ExtraNodes\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t...            None   
3                                         WASHINGTON  DC\tWASHINGTON   
4                                      MIAMI\tMIAMI,          UNITED

Comment: Same of course but with lots of ;;;;;;;;;;;; when using the .csv