# Read from file and split into sections separated in python

Tags: python, string

I have similar problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60524952/from-csv-read-only-or-split-into-sections-separated-by-string), because I would like to read in the unv file having following structure:

```
         1         1        10         6
 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030
 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030
 -6.6630E+000 -1.7367E-001 -2.1252E+000 -2.5218E+000  4.2036E+000 -8.1640E+000
 -5.1128E+000 -6.8833E-001 -1.5559E+000 -1.6777E+000  4.6424E+000 -7.8715E+000
 -4.1248E+000 -1.2634E+000 -3.4831E-001 -1.1815E+000  3.9473E+000 -7.5074E+000
 -3.6813E+000 -1.6054E+000  2.8255E-001 -1.6287E+000  2.6445E+000 -8.5538E+000
 -4.0141E+000 -1.9938E+000 -1.3340E+000 -1.2667E+000  3.2966E+000 -1.0588E+001
 -5.6385E+000 -8.0812E-001 -2.2863E+000 -2.0393E+000  4.5700E+000 -9.3787E+000
 -5.0408E+000 -1.6359E+000 -1.6201E+000 -7.3298E-001  4.5651E+000 -9.7675E+000
 -4.8265E+000 -1.6681E+000 -2.2328E+000 -1.0329E+000  4.4670E+000 -1.0074E+001
```

The first number after lots of spaces of the first line (--> "1") represents ID and increases in the original file from 1 to ~90 000. Another four numbers in the first line (1, 10, 6) don't change. There are always six columns in the rows from 2 to 11 in the scientific notation.

I would like to extract the IDs by regular expressions. So far I tried:

```
import re
l = "         1         1        10         6"
y = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', l)
```

It helps and delivers to me the ID "1". However it matches the numbers from other lines. My wish is to find regular expression that applies only to the lines that have 4 numbers (like the line 1).

Comment: `(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=(?:[^\d\n]*\b\d+\b){4}))[^\d\n]*\K\d+`, with `pip install regex` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/aJuXA9/1)).

Comment: your solution doesn't work: "error: bad escape \G at position 3"

Comment: I said: `pip install regex`. Then use `import regex as re` and enjoy. If you need to process multiline text, add `re.M` as an option. Certainly it is better solved in several steps. And you may do that without any regex, too, see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to design a regular expression that applies. You can simply divide the rows into columns and know how many there are.

```
import re

lines = '''
         1         1        10         6
 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030
 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030
 -6.6630E+000 -1.7367E-001 -2.1252E+000 -2.5218E+000  4.2036E+000 -8.1640E+000
 -5.1128E+000 -6.8833E-001 -1.5559E+000 -1.6777E+000  4.6424E+000 -7.8715E+000
 -4.1248E+000 -1.2634E+000 -3.4831E-001 -1.1815E+000  3.9473E+000 -7.5074E+000
 -3.6813E+000 -1.6054E+000  2.8255E-001 -1.6287E+000  2.6445E+000 -8.5538E+000
 -4.0141E+000 -1.9938E+000 -1.3340E+000 -1.2667E+000  3.2966E+000 -1.0588E+001
 -5.6385E+000 -8.0812E-001 -2.2863E+000 -2.0393E+000  4.5700E+000 -9.3787E+000
 -5.0408E+000 -1.6359E+000 -1.6201E+000 -7.3298E-001  4.5651E+000 -9.7675E+000
 -4.8265E+000 -1.6681E+000 -2.2328E+000 -1.0329E+000  4.4670E+000 -1.0074E+001
 
         2         1        10         6
 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030
 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030 -1.0000E+030
 -6.6630E+000 -1.7367E-001 -2.1252E+000 -2.5218E+000  4.2036E+000 -8.1640E+000
 -5.1128E+000 -6.8833E-001 -1.5559E+000 -1.6777E+000  4.6424E+000 -7.8715E+000
 -4.1248E+000 -1.2634E+000 -3.4831E-001 -1.1815E+000  3.9473E+000 -7.5074E+000
 -3.6813E+000 -1.6054E+000  2.8255E-001 -1.6287E+000  2.6445E+000 -8.5538E+000
 -4.0141E+000 -1.9938E+000 -1.3340E+000 -1.2667E+000  3.2966E+000 -1.0588E+001
 -5.6385E+000 -8.0812E-001 -2.2863E+000 -2.0393E+000  4.5700E+000 -9.3787E+000
 -5.0408E+000 -1.6359E+000 -1.6201E+000 -7.3298E-001  4.5651E+000 -9.7675E+000
 -4.8265E+000 -1.6681E+000 -2.2328E+000 -1.0329E+000  4.4670E+000 -1.0074E+001
 
'''

for line in lines.splitlines():
    cols = line.split()
    if (len(cols) == 4):
        print(cols[0])
```

Output:

```
1
2
```